# One div with input and other div inside

Tags: html, css

how can I get the `input` aligned with the div `#submitKeyword` ?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B45P5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="searchKeywords">
<input id="inputKeyword" type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
<div id="submitKeyword"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchKeywords { 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
margin-top: 70px; 
text-align: center; 
}

.searchKeywords #inputKeyword {
display: inline-block; 
height: 45px; 
width: 150px; 
border: 2px solid;
}

.searchKeywords #submitKeyword { 
display: inline-block; 
width: 115px; 
height: 45px; 
border: 1px solid #000; 
background-image: url('/www/assets/newImages/gallery/Lupa.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.searchKeywords { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: 70px; 
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchKeywords #inputKeyword {

    height: 45px; 
    width: 150px; 
    border: 2px solid;

}

.searchKeywords #submitKeyword { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 115px; 
    height: 45px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    background-image: url('/www/assets/newImages/gallery/Lupa.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/B45P5/1/

Comment: Ok, but in that way the `input` wont be with the same height as `#submitKeyword`

Comment: change the height of input field height: 41px; Input field has default 1px padding from top and bottom. Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/B45P5/13/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with `display:table`. Also use `margin: auto` instead of `text-align:center` to align your elements in the middle.

**css**

```
.searchKeywords { 
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}

.searchKeywords #inputKeyword {
    display: table-cell; 
    height: 45px; 
    width: 150px; 
    border: 2px solid;
}

.searchKeywords #submitKeyword { 
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 115px; 
    height: 45px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    background-image: url('/www/assets/newImages/gallery/Lupa.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B45P5/11/)